# Why doesn't my Fontello icons work in Firefox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, icons, webfonts, fontello

My Fontello icons do not show up in Firefox in my Ruby on Rails application. This is [Fontello](http://fontello.com/). Does anyone have any idea why this could be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fontello for the Rails asset pipeline. [Github Link](https://github.com/blackxored/fontello-rails)

Add this line to your application's Gemfile, in your assets group if you prefer:

> gem 'fontello-rails'

And then execute:

> $ bundle install

Or install it yourself as:

> $ gem install fontello-rails